# router-outlets and shared components

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am using angular-nativescript and want to include some components on every site.
I was able to achieve this using code below in my app.component.

`<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet><my-component></my-component>`

This doesn't work (as mentioned in documentation). Using router-outlet in the same way works, but I can't navigate back. How do I solve this? I played around with router-outlet in a component and child-routes, but I am getting mixed results.

When I just put the component on every page manually, they are created as new instances and a lot of code gets executed wastefully (I pull data from server and populate arrays in my-component)

Answer (score 0):

According to a discussion on NativeScript's [github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/558) this behaves as it should.

page-router-outlet navigates to a new page (like a native app should do) and my-component is not present there. router-outlet does not navigate anywhere, just swaps it's content and back button tries to navigate to a previous page. Since there is none, the application closes.

The solution is to add the component manually on each page.